# IOS Crashlog Unknown Process Unknown Type

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8

```
Incident Identifier: 3789E9E8-8694-4135-9FCB-727E857836E3
CrashReporter Key:   a97c29bcf448c3a983916511bdc9d6ded9203091
Hardware Model:      iPad3,4
OS Version:          iPhone OS 8.1 (12B410)
Kernel Version:      Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Tue Oct  7 00:05:19 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2783.3.13~4/RELEASE_ARM_S5L8955X
Date:                2014-10-21 12:32:02 -0400
Time since snapshot: 33 ms

Free pages:                              1784
Active pages:                            7709
Inactive pages:                          3626
Speculative pages:                       552
Throttled pages:                         55986
Purgeable pages:                         0
Wired pages:                             183473
File-backed pages:                       11330
Anonymous pages:                         557
Compressions:                            49937
Decompressions:                          6105
Compressor Size:                         99
Uncompressed Pages in Compressor:        189
Page Size:                               4096
Largest process:   asgaard

Processes
     Name       |                            |     CPU Time|     rpages|       purgeable| recent_max| lifetime_max| fds |  [reason]         | (state)

        cfprefsd          0.017         112                0           -           260   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (daemon) (idle)
com.apple.datami          0.022         109                0           -           418   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (daemon) (idle)
   nsurlsessiond        111.668         521                0           -          1688   50   [vm-pageshortage]   (daemon)
            bird          5.977        1014                0           -          3067   50                       (daemon)
          cloudd         17.527        1075                0           -          2985  100                       (daemon)
      MobileMail          9.825        5067                0           -         13721   50                       (continuous)
             lsd          7.307         600                0           -          1483   50                       (daemon)
            tccd          2.667         235                0           -           834   50                       (daemon)
             kbd          2.919         571                0           -          2150   50                       (daemon)
         asgaard         10.787       14214                0           -         18707   50                       (location) (frontmost) (resume)
        BTServer         43.065         508                0           -          1948   50                       (daemon)
       lockdownd          3.776         268                0           -          1274   50                       (daemon)
         imagent          2.402         468                0           -          2413   50                       (daemon)
identityservices          3.946         573                0           -          1861   50                       (daemon)
       locationd         76.013        1326                0           -          3782   50                       (daemon)
      discoveryd         15.366         531                0           -          1284  100                       (daemon)
           wifid         23.145         512                0           -          1542   50                       (daemon)
   iaptransportd         21.473         298                0           -           856   50                       (daemon)
    mediaserverd          8.960         737                0           -          3217   50                       (daemon)
         syslogd         19.553         194                0           -           438   50                       (daemon)
          powerd          6.748         193                0           -           467   50                       (daemon)
            apsd          7.965         524                0           -          1684   50                       (daemon)
        networkd         17.141         550                0           -          1502   50                       (daemon)
        sharingd          2.129         556                0           -          1768   50                       (daemon)
     dataaccessd          5.969         981                0           -          2469   50                       (daemon)
            iapd         39.287         637                0           -          1769   50                       (daemon)
     SpringBoard        202.683        6662                0           -         39420   50                      
      backboardd        572.390       14074                0           -          5848   50                       (daemon)
  UserEventAgent         61.648         699                0           -          2433  100                       (daemon)
         configd         18.276         399                0           -          1247   50                       (daemon)
    fairplayd.A2          1.851         144                0           -          1405   50                       (daemon)
       fseventsd          5.084         323                0           -          1248   50                       (daemon)
      assertiond          7.114         267                0           -           875   50                       (daemon)
       distnoted          1.945         167                0           -           296   50                       (daemon)
discoveryd_helpe          0.121         118                0           -           623   50                       (daemon)
   wirelessproxd          0.874         211                0           -           898   50                       (daemon)
      aggregated        182.443         886                0           -          2443   50                       (daemon)
filecoordination          1.134         277                0           -           885  100                       (daemon)
             ubd          0.066         177                0           -           685   50                       (daemon)
     touchsetupd          0.111         150                0           -           647   50                       (daemon)
CommCenterClassi          4.208         503                0           -          1689   50                       (daemon)
         notifyd         17.592         269                0           -           333   50                       (daemon)

**End**
```

So the app I'm running (that crashed) is called asgaard

```
    asgaard         10.787       14214                0           -         18707   50                       (location) (frontmost) (resume)
```

Am i running against a memory limit and if so how can I diagnose this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I was using too much memory

As asgaard was using `14214` rpages it turned out i was loading too many images into virtual memory.